# How to recursively capture user input

Tags: go

I'm trying to capture the input of a bunch of numbers in Go. I am not allowed to do for loops. User input is multi-lined. However the function below is not returning the expected results of an `[]int`, it instead returns with an empty array. Why is this? Or is there another way to capture multi-lined user input without for loops?

```
func input_to_list() []int {
    fmt.Print("continuously enter text: ")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    user_input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    print(user_input)
    var result []int
    if user_input == "\n" {
        return result
    }
    return append(result, input_to_list()...)
}
```

Comment: That's a slice, not an array. An empty array isn't really possible in Go (except an array of zero length, i.e. `[0]int`, which is probably useless).

Comment: Sorry I am new to go. Does this prevent me from capturing the input or is the problem elsewhere?

Comment: You're never assigning anything to `result` (except the result of the recursive empty result), so it makes sense you never get any output.

Comment: No, the note about slices vs arrays is just an aside about your use of terminology.

Answer (score 4):

> How to recursively capture user input?
>
> I am not allowed to do for loops.

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func readInt(rdr *bufio.Reader, n []int) []int {
    line, err := rdr.ReadString('\n')
    line = strings.TrimSpace(line)
    if i, err := strconv.Atoi(line); err == nil {
        n = append(n, i)
    }
    if err == io.EOF || strings.ToLower(line) == "end" {
        return n
    }
    return readInt(rdr, n)
}

func ReadInts() []int {
    fmt.Print("enter integers:\n")
    var n []int
    rdr := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    return readInt(rdr, n)
}

func main() {
    n := ReadInts()
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

Output:

```
enter integers:
42
7
end
[42 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function never assigns any value to `result`.

```
func input_to_list() []int {
    /* ... */
    var result []int                          // Create empty `result` slice
    if user_input == "\n" {
        return result                         // Return empty result slice
    }
    return append(result, input_to_list()...) // Combine two empty slices, and return the (still) empty slice
}
```

Let's step through:

1. You create an empty slice called `result`
2. If `user_input` is empty, you return the result immediately.
3. If `user_input` is not empty, you call `input_to_list()` recursively, and add its (empty) result to your empty result, then return that (still) empty result.

To get your desired behavior, you should be doing something (other than just checking for empty) with `user_input`.  Probably something related to `strconv.Atoi` or similar, then adding that to `result`.

Comment: Thanks for giving hints to the user to reach the goal (this is clearly homework) instead of giving the solution.